# Getting 404 page error while calling the index controller - module

Tags: magento, module

Module is working on local server but is not working after moving to the Linux server.Im sure all the file are in caps only please point out the error where i missed

```html
 Apptha_Subscription.xml

<config>        
    <modules>        
        <Apptha_Subscription>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Apptha_Subscription>
    </modules>
</config>

confix.xml

<config>
    <modules>
        <Apptha_Subscription>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Apptha_Subscription>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <subscription>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Apptha_Subscription</module>
                    <frontName>subscription</frontName>
                </args>
            </subscription>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <subscription>
                    <file>subscription.xml</file>
                </subscription>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Apptha_Subscription>
                    <files>
                        <default>Apptha_subscription.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Apptha_Subscription>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <global>                       
        <blocks>
            <subscription>
                <class>Apptha_Subscription_Block</class>
            </subscription>
        </blocks>
        <models>
          <subscription>
                <class>Apptha_Subscription_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>subscription_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </subscription>
            <subscription_mysql4>
                <class>Apptha_Subscription_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                 <subscriptionpaymentdetails>
                        <table>subscription_payment_details</table>
                 </subscriptionpaymentdetails>
                 <subscriptionorderdetails>
                        <table>subscription_order_details</table>
                 </subscriptionorderdetails>    
                </entities>
                </subscription_mysql4>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <subscription>
                <class>Apptha_Subscription_Helper</class>
            </subscription>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
 <routers>
   <subscription>
     <use>admin</use>
  <args>
    <module>Apptha_Subscription</module>
    <frontName>subscription</frontName>
  </args>
   </subscription>
 </routers>
  </admin>  
   <global>
    <events>
      <customer_register_success>
            <observers>
                <airhotels>
                   <type>singleton</type>
                   <class>Apptha_Subscription_Model_Observer</class>
                   <method>customer_register_success</method>
                </airhotels>
            </observers>
         </customer_register_success>         
     </events>
   </global>
</config>
block 
Subscription.php

class Apptha_Subscription_Block_Subscription extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
 /**
  * Method to get the layouts
  * 
  * @return void
  */ 
 public function _prepareLayout()
    {
  return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }        
    
    /**
     * Method to get the initial details of before payment of customer
     *
     * @return array
     */
    
    public function intialDetailsBPay()
    {
     if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
     {
      $customerData   = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
      $customerId  = $customerData->getId();
    
      return $intialDetailsBPay  = Mage::getModel('subscription/subscriptionpaymentdetails')->load($customerId,'customer_id');
     }
      
    }
}
<p>controller</p>
IndexController.php

class Apptha_Subscription_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

 /*
     * this method privides default action.
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {    

        /*
         * Initialization of Mage_Core_Model_Layout model
         */
        $this->loadLayout();
 
        /*
         * Building page according to layout confuration
         */
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function insertsubscribeAction()
    {
     $this->loadLayout();
     
     Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('subscription_subscription');
     $this->renderLayout();
    }
    
}
   layout/subscription.xml

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!--Page handle -->
    <subscription_index_index>
     <!-- reference tag specifies the block where we a going to add child block -->
      <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <!-- Our page content block -->
            <block type="subscription/subscription" name="subscription" template="subscription/subscription.phtml">    
            </block>
        </reference>
    </subscription_index_index> 
    <subscription_subscribe_insertsubscribe>    
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
       <reference name="content">
            <!-- Our page content block -->
            <block type="subscription/subscription" name="subscription" template="subscription/paypalbutton.phtml">    
            </block>
        </reference>
    </subscription_subscribe_insertsubscribe>   
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same module is working on Localhost but not after migration, there is high possibility that permissions are not proper for the migrated files on your linux server. I will suggest please check permissions for all module files.

Secondly, make sure there is no dependency which is remaining to be migrated.

Comment: Did you check file permissions?

Comment: Thank you..

Finally i fix that issue.
Issue occurs due to sensitiveness i gave the controller folder name    in Caps(Controller)

This is name should be in small letters only